# Android Edittext won't center horizontally

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I have tried the answers in a few similiar questions but I can't get the edittext with id=email to center on the screen, it sits to the left side of the screen.  I do change the width of the edittext programatically, but then I reset the gravity programatically.  I don't understand why it isnt centering.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#333333"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:id="@+id/edt"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="EMAIL"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:textColor="#67bca2"
    android:textColorHint="@drawable/selector"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="PASSWORD"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:textColor="#67bca2"
    android:textColorHint="@drawable/selector"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/zeus_getdevicemdpi"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:onClick="checklogin"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/zeus_getdevicemdpi"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:id="@+id/createNew"
    android:onClick="register"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    email.setTypeface(custom_font);
    email.getLayoutParams().width = width/2;
    email.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Add  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to EditText

Comment: tried that and it didn't workI

Comment: use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for the `EditText`.

Comment: try to use **android:layout_centerInParent="true"**

Comment: Choose `ConstraintLayout`, it's new, better and easy.

Answer (score 1):

First, for UI questions, please get used to attach a snapshot. Then, please tell that one view is already working, the other is not. I didn't take much to see which part you're missing, but please Jonny Man make some effort before you post on SO.
What you need to change is:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

You're confusing the view itself with its content (the text) btw.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EMAIL"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:textColor="#67bca2"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"/>
```